# CGKeyCode table

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgkeycode

Is there a table or some kind of utility with which I can find the CGKeyCode of a key? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  NSLog(@"keycode: %hu", [theEvent keyCode]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get them one at a time:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    CGEventRef cgEvent = [theEvent CGEvent];

    NSLog(@"%hu", CGEventGetIntegerValueField(cgEvent, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode));
}
```

They also seem to be listed in Events.h.